# Billboard-like Representation For Spheres OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glm-math

The world is made of spheres. Since drawing a sphere in OpenGL takes a lot of triangles, I thought it would be faster to use a point and radius to represent a sphere, then use Billboarding in OpenGL to draw it. The current approach I took causes adjacent spheres to not touch when rotating the view.

**Here's an example:**

There are two spheres:

**Sphere 1** *Position* (0, 0, -3) *Radius* (0.5)

**Sphere 2** *Position* (-1, 0, -3) *Radius* (0.5)

The projection matrix is defined using:

```
glm::perspective(glm::radians(120.0f), 1.0f, 1.0f, 100.0f);
```

**Image 1**: When there is no rotation, it looks as expected.

[image: No rotation]

**Image 2**: When there **is** rotation, billboarding responds to the camera as expected, **but** the spheres' do not touch anymore. And if they were actually spheres that were next to each other, you would expect them to touch.

[image: Rotation]

**What I have tried:**

- I tried `GL_POINTS`, they didn't work as good because it didn't seem to
  handle the depth test correctly for me.
- I tried a geometry shader    that creates a square before and after
  the projection matrix was    applied.

**Here's the code I have now that created the images:**

*Vertex Shader*

```
#version 460

layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout(location = 1) in float radius;


out float radius_vs;

void main()
{

    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
    radius_vs = radius;
}
```

*Geometry Shader*

```
#version 460

layout(points) in;
layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices = 4) out;
layout(location = 2) uniform mat4 view_mat;
layout(location = 3) uniform mat4 projection_mat;

in float radius_vs[];
out vec2 bounds;

void main()
{
    vec3 x_dir = vec3(view_mat[0][0], view_mat[1][0], view_mat[2][0]) * radius_vs[0];
    vec3 y_dir = vec3(view_mat[0][1], view_mat[1][1], view_mat[2][1]) * radius_vs[0];


    mat4 fmat = projection_mat * view_mat;


    gl_Position = fmat * vec4(gl_in[0].gl_Position.xyz - x_dir - y_dir, 1.0f);
    bounds = vec2(-1.0f, -1.0f);
    EmitVertex();

    gl_Position = fmat * vec4(gl_in[0].gl_Position.xyz - x_dir + y_dir, 1.0f);
    bounds = vec2(-1.0f, 1.0f);
    EmitVertex();

    gl_Position = fmat * vec4(gl_in[0].gl_Position.xyz + x_dir - y_dir, 1.0f);
    bounds = vec2(1.0f, -1.0f);
    EmitVertex();

    gl_Position = fmat * vec4(gl_in[0].gl_Position.xyz + x_dir + y_dir, 1.0f);
    bounds = vec2(1.0f, 1.0f);
    EmitVertex();

    EndPrimitive();
}
```

*Fragment Shader*

```
#version 460

out vec4 colorOut;

in vec2 bounds;

void main()
{
    vec2 circCoord = bounds;
    if (dot(circCoord, circCoord) > 1.0) 
    {
        discard;
    }
    colorOut = vec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: *"not touch when rotating the view"* - since you're using perspective projection, the size of the objects depends on the "depth" (z coordinate in view space)

Comment: Further note, the apparent distance (projected distance) between 2 objects (points in space) depends on the point of view.

Comment: Read [this maths](https://paroj.github.io/gltut/Illumination/Tut13%20Correct%20Chicanery.html) about using a better approach than yours.